# WCF Async Method only working when debugging

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a weird issue, I'm building a Universal App and everything works when I'm debugging but when I run without debugging the emulator tries to open the application and then crashes.

Here is the code I know is failing:

```
private void MenuPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   SetItemSource();
}

private async void SetItemSource()
{
   MenuItems =  await AppWinService.GetMenuEntriesAsync();     
   ItemSource = new ObservableCollection<AlphaKeyGroup<Menu>>
         ((AlphaKeyGroup<Menu>.CreateGroups(MenuItems,
                                            CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, 
                                            s => s.MenuName, 
                                            true)));

   ((CollectionViewSource)Resources["MenuGroups"]).Source = ItemSource;

 }
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `MenuItems` is coming back valid *for all situations*? What happens on timeout?

Why not check for null just to be safe:

```
MenuItems =  await AppWinService.GetMenuEntriesAsync();   

if ((MenuItems != null) && (MenuItems.Any())
{
   ItemSource = new ObservableCollection<AlphaKeyGroup<Menu>>(
                                          (AlphaKeyGroup<Menu>.CreateGroups(MenuItems,
                                           CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, 
                                           s => s.MenuName, 
                                           true)));

  ((CollectionViewSource)Resources["MenuGroups"]).Source = ItemSource;
}
else 
{ 
   MessageBox.Show("Failure to get data"); 
}
```

Comment: Hi, Omega, yes I'm sure it does not fail. I think the issue has to do with my wcf service being found when I debug because the WcfSVHost it turns on next to my clock in the right corner, but when I don't debug nothing happens so I don't know that seems to be a clue of what is happening. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @GroopsGroops I would have to look at more of the code. Maybe along with the check I mentioned, add more checks..maybe the `CreateGroups` call is failing. You need to determine where the **exact** failure point is...for its failing somewhere in the code and without *sanity* if checks, you will never know. I started placing such checks in my code for one never knows when/where code will fail and handling an error by adopting good practices will save one time in the long run. HTH

Comment: Hi Omega, I'm sure is not the service itself is failing but when running in debug mode Visual Studio hosts the service for me but I think somehow I have to host it in IIS configure the app to find it there and that way it will work in both debugging mode and without debugging. I don't know how to do that though.

Comment: I ended up creating a service hosted in IIS but the same problem appears to happen :(

Comment: @GroopsGroops Visual Studio comes with an application to test web services named `WcfTestClient` it can be found in the Visual Studio install directory `Common7\IDE`. Can you test the call in IIS using that? Also instead of making a service call, why not stub out the information returned by the async call, and call that. Run it in debug mode as well as release. If it works try it with no data returned, then with 10 items. In otherwords do negative testing to determine what the web service failure call is.

Comment: I can get my webservice to work but I'm having issues waiting for the async call to finish, so when I'm not debugging the code just runs at the same time and it fails. The WCF service has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: @GroopsGroops Interesting. Then one may need to restructure how the app handles the lack of data during a long wait. That implies that the code is not fully asynchronous in the design implemented.